# Ruby sleep to specific time

Tags: ruby, sleep

How could i write, that my code sleep not for example 5 seconds, but until some time on machine is reached.

not so:

```
sleep(5)
```

but something like:

```
now = DateTime.Now
while now != "14:40:03"
  sleep(0.5)
end
```

how is it correct to do?

Comment: I believe you want to do some task at a particular time? What's the use case? Why not use a cron job?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
require "time"
sleep(Time.parse("14:40:03") - Time.now)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or use the Rufus Scheduler

https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

From the OpenWFEru/ruote project.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rufus-scheduler'

scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

scheduler.in '20m' do
  #do something
end
```

this provide a real passive waiting, no load.

Comment: i try this before, but: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19447467/rufus-scheduler-time-format